# Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Server VES-SQL01, Line 2 Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

Whenever I try running this on a old copy of the database, it runs perfectly.

```
DECLARE @CompanyName AS VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @SQLCommand AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '' 
DECLARE companycursor CURSOR FOR SELECT      
                                    REPLACE([Name],'.','_') as[Name]  
                         FROM        
                                    Company; 

OPEN companycursor 

FETCH companycursor INTO @CompanyName 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 

BEGIN 

    IF @SQLCommand <> '' SET @SQLCommand += 'UNION ALL' 

    SET @SQLCommand += 
    '
    SELECT [Company Name] = ''' + @CompanyName + ''', *
    FROM [' + @CompanyName + '$Sales Line]
    INNER JOIN [' + @CompanyName + '$Sales Header]
    ON [' + @CompanyName + '$Sales Line].[Document No_] = [' + @CompanyName + '$Sales Header].[No_]
    WHERE (YEAR([' + @CompanyName + '$Sales Header].[Posting Date])> CAST(2016 AS int)-1 
    OR YEAR([' + @CompanyName + '$Sales Header].[Posting Date])= CAST(2016 AS int)-1 AND MONTH([' + @CompanyName + '$Sales Header].[Posting Date])> 12-CAST(3 AS int)
    OR YEAR([' + @CompanyName + '$Sales Header].[Posting Date])= CAST(1753 AS int) AND YEAR([' + @CompanyName + '$Sales Header].[Order Date])> CAST(2016 AS int)-1
    OR YEAR([' + @CompanyName + '$Sales Header].[Posting Date])= CAST(1753 AS int) AND YEAR([' + @CompanyName + '$Sales Header].[Order Date])= CAST(2016 AS int)-1 AND MONTH([' + @CompanyName + '$Sales Header].[Order Date])> 12-CAST(3 AS int)) 
    AND YEAR([' + @CompanyName + '$Sales Header].[Posting Date]) < CAST(2017 AS int)+1
'

    FETCH companycursor INTO @CompanyName 
END; 

EXEC(@SQLCommand)

--PRINT @SQLCommand 

CLOSE companycursor 

DEALLOCATE companycursor
```

However when I try running it on the live database is gives an error.

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Server VES-SQL01, Line 2
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric .

Comment: My guess would be that you now have a `[company].[Name]` value which is numeric (or at least will implicitly convert to a numeric type), so when you build your dynamic SQL to run against your NAV database, it's trying to use the `+` operator to add this numeric value to the `varchar` you're building. Try wrapping all the `@CompanyName` values in your `SET` command with `CONVERT` like this: `CONVERT(VARCHAR, @CompanyName)` and see if that fixes it. Otherwise, please provide a complete distinct list of the `[Company].[Name]` values from the old and new databases so that we can diagnose for you.

Comment: side note - your sql suggests a flawed database design, in that data (company name) is used as meta data (table name). In a correct design, the company would be just another column in the table.

Comment: What are the data types of fields [Document No_], [No_]?

Comment: @sepupic both are nvarchar(20)

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Exactly, this is common in a Microsoft Dynamics NAV database. That's why I build in te loop on company name.

Comment: Please add the execution plan, even estimated, there will be convert implicit somewhere

Comment: @3N1GM4: I don't think the problem lies in de company table. I've build in the company loop in every SQL. And this is the only SQL where this problem occurs.

Comment: I mean, not for cursor, please print the commands generated, pick one of them, paste into query window and generate estimated plan for it

Comment: So you can guarantee you have no values in `Company.Name` which implicitly convert to a numeric type? If it runs on one dataset without issue, but not on another, that would suggest some difference between the datasets is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

These debug really nicely by replacing EXEC with SELECT, and then copying/pasting the output in a query window and executing. You can many times double-click the red SQL Server error and the cursor will jump right to the problem.

Not the solution, but a way to get to the solution very eloquently I think.